Meaning of "blunk"
Wordle accepts "blunk" as a correct word, but neither Google Translate nor ChatGPT give a translation.
ChatGPT:

If "blunk" is a valid choice in Wordle, then it might be an English word, even if it's not very common. Sometimes, in word games like Wordle, lesser-known or dialectal words are accepted. However, in standard English, "blunk" is not a recognized word.

Google translate:



What does it mean?

Strange, I don't know if Wordle has updated its word list but when I was doing a statistical analysis (the list is embedded inside the app and you can extract it) it had a limited vocabulary of 2316 words, far less than the number of 5 letter words in English. And blunk was not one of them.

Is the Wordle of today, august 29th

Yes, they seem to have rebuilt the app under the skin. I can no longer find a built in word list

@PeterJennings - the smaller list of 2K were only candidate answers there has always been a larger list of words acceptable for guesses but not a candidate to be an answer https://www.reddit.com/r/wordle/comments/s4tcw8/a_note_on_wordles_word_list/

Why did you even try blunk when you eliminated the b at blunt?
And I notice that the dictionary linked here to assess my input also doesn't like blunk.

Well, my question is not about figuring out game strategies in Wordle  Actually I don't have any strategy, it's all random.

@MartinSmith Ah, I didn't know that.

For word definitions, I'd go to a dictionary. Why did you choose Google Translate and ChatGPT? They seem very odd sources to look at.

Wordle accepts it because it is actually a word, although it is seldom used and is some kind of a slang term. Basically, it means "to ruin" or "to mess up". Note that this word is used in both American and British English, and is very rarely used (especially in formal contexts) in both.
Here's some references:

Wiktionary definition of "blunk"
Collins dictionary definition of "blunk"


Thanks for the answers, they are very helpful and explanatory. I would accept the three but it is not possible.

@Danielillo So did my answer help you? I'll be very glad to hear that! :)

According to Green's, it's an adjective meaning drunk, which may have been formed as a combination of the words blotto/blind and drunk.

Slang I guess?.-

Yes, it is a slang. Although I found somewhat of a different definition (see my answer below). Probably both are correct.

Blunk is in the OED.
The entry for blunk verb is labeled Obsolete (To turn aside, blench, flinch, shrink) or dialect (‘To spoil a thing, to mismanage any business’ [Jamieson]).
The entry for blunk noun is labeled Scottish. (In plural. ‘Linen or cotton cloths which are wrought for being printed; calicoes’ [Jamieson]).
Make of it what you will, but it seems like Wordle is getting desperate.
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)

Why would acceptance of this indicate "Wordle is getting desperate"? Blunk wasn't the answer - just a term that Wordle accepted along the way

@MartinSmith — Wordle’s inclusion of obsolete, dialect, or Scottish words in its dictionary is a stretch.

He just grabbed a scrabble dictionary and used it as the list of acceptable guesses.   Because of that, it does have some rarely-used words in it.  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114419/what-dictionary-is-wordle-based-on
